# Price selector from online store

Tags: xpath

I want to extract the price of certain product from banggood (i.e. http://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-IMAX-B6-Digital-RC-Lipo-NiMH-battery-Balance-Charger-p-46220.html) using google spreadsheets.

Right now I can grab the price but also other values using this string:

```
=IMPORTXML(A6 ; "//*[contains(@class, 'now')]")
```

I get this:

> 21.68
>   Buy it now

I just want to get the actual value that is within this:

```
<div class="now" oriprice="21.68">363.69</div>
```

it should be the "353.69" alone, (that's the price in mi currency , MX).

I also tried this:

```
=IMPORTXML(A6 ; "//*[contains(@class, 'now')] and string('oriprice')")
```

but returns TRUE not the value

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

21.68 is actually a correct result.
When you do scraping you should always consider real server response, but not what you see on scree.

So go to source and see real HTML. See picture below (that is the page u mentioned)

[image]

and reason why u get Buy Now is

[image]

So write this

```
=IMPORTXML(A6 ; "//*[@class = 'now']")
```

Comment: And how do I delete the "Buy it now" text, that text is inside the class "buynow" , is there a way to narrow the result to the exact text "buy" ?

Comment: @CarlosEsponda yes there is a way, see my updated answer. just avoid contains function and use strict equal.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get 21.68 is because that's the price in US dollars, which appears to be the site's base currency.

When you View Source, as Dmytro suggests, you might see a different value in the `div` containing the price.  I see 14.26, for example, because that's the price in my currency.

This value is being updated after the page has been loaded.  That page's Javascript is detecting your country, setting a cookie with your currency in it, and then making an AJAX call to this page:

`http://www.banggood.com/index.php?com=product&t=initViewHistory&utm_medium=&product_id=46220`

That is returning an HTML snippet with the price in your own currency, which the main page's Javascript is then inserting into the page.

Your problem, as far as the spreadsheet goes, is that when you use Google Sheets to fetch that page (a) Google Sheets won't run the Javascript and (b) Google's request to the store's site will probably be detected as being in the US and so even if the JS were run it wouldn't actually change the price.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.